# What Cannot be Expressed by Relational Algebra?

Tags: relational-algebra

What are some queries that cannot be expressed by the basic operations of relational algebra?

What I know so far are that aggregate functions like average, total number cannot be expressed? What others are there?

Answer (score 2):

Any query for which [generalized] transitive closure is required.

Is there a flight path from Capetown to Wellington ?
How long will a train ride from London to Sofia take, how many times will I have to change trains and how long will I be kept waiting in the train station ?